# Eval in for with two arguments

Tags: eval

I wrote two function in a script

```
for TYPE in $LIST_TYPE
do
    egrep -v 'dc02|vh|dc03kh00|r0' $REPORT_37 | grep CP_ASK | grep $DC |awk -F, -v type=$TYPE '$NF == type { print $1 }' > ./$DC_'type_'$TYPE
    EMPTY_TYPE_$TYPE=$(cat $DC'_type_'$TYPE | wc -l)
done
```

the second will use in an other for EMPTY_TYPE_$TYPE
so I did

```
for TYPE in $LIST_TYPE
do
    eval echo \$EMPTY_TYPE_$TYPE
    egrep -v 'dc02|vh|dc03kh00|r[0-2]' $REPORT_33 | grep NOT | grep $DC |awk -F, -v days=$DAYS -v version=$VERSION -v type=$TYPE '{if (($(NF-15)  > days || $(NF-02)!= version) && ($(NF-20) == type))  print $1}' | eval tail -n \ EMPTY_TYPE_$TYPE > ./$DC'_TO_WORK'
done
```

the problem is that I get error

```
awk -F, -v days=180 -v version=6.7 -v type=E '{if (($(NF-15)  > days || $(NF-02)!= version) && ($(NF-20) == type))  print $1}' + eval tail -n '$EMPTY_TYPE_E'
```

when I run only the command (not in bash script)

```
egrep -v 'dc02|vh|dc03kh00|r[0-2]' report_33.20170720.075339 | grep NOT | grep $DC |awk -F, -v days=$DAYS -v version=$VERSION  '{if (($(NF-15)  > days || $(NF-02)!= version) && ($(NF-20) == "A"))  print $1}' | eval tail -n \$EMPTY_TYPE_$TYPE
```

it works.

Comment: This is complete gibberish. You should at least show the value of the variables you use (like `$LIST_TYPE`), and say what you expect your script to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the first function 
EMPTY_TYPE_$TYPE=$(cat $DC'*type*'$TYPE | wc -l) should be 
eval EMPTY_TYPE_$TYPE=$(cat $DC'*type*'$TYPE | wc -l)

that was the issue